# Как записать русскую строку в бинарный файл, а после прочитать?

Tags: c++, fstream

Записываю и считываю данные этим кодом

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int n;
    char f[8];
};

int main(){
    setlocale(0, "");   
    string path = "file.txt";
     
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    if(!fin.is_open()){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        Node N;
        N.n = 228;
        cout << "Введите f: " << endl;
        char Lol[8];
        cin >> Lol;
        strcpy_s(N.f, Lol);
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(path, ios::app);
        if(!fout.is_open()) cout << "GLOBAL ERROR!" << endl;
        else {
            cout << "Новые данные успешно сохранены!" << endl;
            fout.write((char*)&N, sizeof(Node));
        }
        fout.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;
        Node Nd;
        while(fin.read((char*)&Nd, sizeof(Node))){
        
        }
        cout << Nd.n << "\t" << Nd.f << "\t";
    }
    fin.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если я ввожу данные на русском
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, то после чтения выдает иероглифы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выкрутиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо у вас буквы читаются из консоли в кодировке досовской кодировке CP866, а вам нужны другая однобайтовая - Windows1251. Кодировку консоли можно поменять так:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Кроме того, у вас пачка проблем с потенциальным переполнением массива или отваливанием заверщающего нуля. Например после чтения этих 8 букв из файла вывод `Nd.f` начнет читать за пределами массива и будет неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

замените сетлокал на

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Можно попробовать:

```
std::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, 1000, res, 1000);
```

Вопрос уже был:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693010/problem-using-multibytetowidechar?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa